# Issue with DocuSign authentication within SugarCRM

Tags: plugins, integration, sugarcrm, docusignapi

We have SugarCRM Enterprise, Version 7.10.2.0 (On-Demand) and tried to install latest version (v1.5.62) of DocuSign plugin (https://sugarexchange.sugarcrm.com/apps/188/sugar-connector-to-docusign) on SugarCRM.

We followed the installation documentation (https://help.upcurvecloud.com/sugardocusign/Sugar_Connector_to_DocuSign.pdf)

Issue: Once we try to login then Error popups "DocuSign Error!" (Screenshot attached)

[image]

Any help will be highly appreciable.

Regards

Comment: You may want to replace that screenshot with a version that has the web address and the email address blurred/redacted.

Answer (score 0):

In your Sugar instance go to [Administration -> System Settings -> View Log](https://support.sugarcrm.com/Documentation/Sugar_Versions/7.10/Ent/Administration_Guide/System/#View_Log) and check the log for `FATAL` messages during the attempted login time.

E.g. a possible fatal message could be `[FATAL] Platform name violation: unknown platform (<used platform name of connector goes here>)`.
Since Sugar 7.10 the platform parameter during authorization is limited to  platforms known by your instance. Unknown platforms will be rejected and authorization will fail.
This could be the problem if the connector has yet to be updated for this new behavior.

If so either the provider of the connector or you should add the platform to the instance. E.g. by adding the file `custom/Extension/application/Ext/Platforms/docusign_connector.php` with contents:

```
<?php
$platforms[] = '<used platform name of connector goes here>';
```

However this is just a guess of what the problem could be as I have not seen your Sugar's log.

If your have any other fatal error messages, feel free to share.

Edit: Actually the [platform enforcing seems to be a 7.11 thing](https://community.sugarcrm.com/docs/DOC-5875-tutorial-how-to-register-custom-platforms-in-sugar-instances) rather than a 7.10 thing. So even if you do see an error as described above, it could only to be a warning (for future version compatibility reasons), rather than the actual source of the problem experienced by you.

So make sure to look for other errors as well.